# How to filter and print selective map object in key value format

Tags: arrays, string, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to filter key from a hash map and print in hybrid key value format. I have the same logic working well for csv format as below. In below code, i am selecting only few of the features from response object and returning as comma separated value.

```
public String mycsvformat(Response response, String[] selectedFeature) {
       return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(response.getId()),
            Arrays.stream(selectedFeature)
                    .map(f -> response.getFeature().get(f))
                    .map(v -> v == null ? "" : v.toString())
    )
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

**Output:**

```
id1,feature1Value,feature3Value,feature4Value
```

Response Class -

```
public class Response {
    private String id;
    private Map<String, Object> feature;
}
```

Now I need to print the response in below format:

```
id1    feature1Key=feature1Value,feature3Key=feature3Value,feature4Key=feature4Value
```

Tab separation after id and rest all in key value pair. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet can help.

```java
Arrays.stream(selectedFeature)
      .filter(response.getFeature()::containsKey)
      .map(f -> String.format("%s=%s", f, response.getFeature()
                                                         .get(f)
                                                         .toString()))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(",", String.format("%s\t", response.getId()), ""));
```

Assuming you need to just print the `id` value when none of the selected features match.